# Hide and show calandar visibility when listview scrolled- xamarin.forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app which contains a calendar view at top and a listview just below it.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is when the listview under that calendar view scrolled down the calendar should hide so that the listview will take the whole screen.When the listview scrolled up the calender should re appear to previous state.Is this possible with xamarin,forms?

**My xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="0.8*"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Calendar x:Name="Calendar"
           Grid.Row="0">
          </Calendar>   
       <ListView x:Name="listView"
              ItemAppearing="Handle_ItemAppearing"
              Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            ...
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout"
                 Grid.Row="2">
        <Button></Button>
        <Button></Button>       
        </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

**My xaml.cs file and what I am tried**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    int lastItemIndex;
    int currentItemIndex;

    public MainPage()
    {
        ...       
    }

    void Handle_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        string item = e.Item as string;
        currentItemIndex = Items.IndexOf(item);
        if (currentItemIndex > lastItemIndex)
        {
            Calendar.IsVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Calendar.IsVisible = true;
        }
        lastItemIndex = currentItemIndex;
    }
}
```

Somehow its not working. Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try to test both functionalities separately. Can you hit a breakpoint in  Handle_ItemAppearing when you expect it to (scrolling down in your listview)? Can you hide your calendar manually, e.g. by setting a timer that will set IsVisible to false?

Comment: @Mouse On Mars bro I can manually hide the calendar view.But it leaves a white screen for the entire space of calender.the listview still at its postion, not taking the entire area

Comment: @AndroDevil may i know which calendar you use?

Comment: @PrissyEve Hi, I used syncfusion calander

Comment: syncfusion is a paid calendar or free

Comment: @PrissyEve it is free for single developer whose working company have less than 1 million in revenue..Otherwise it is paid.

Comment: @PrissyEve if you are looking for free control, you can use https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to put the calendar to the [header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#headers-and-footers) of listView.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="450"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView x:Name="listView"
          Grid.Row="0">

        <!--put the listview here-->
        <ListView.Header>
            <Calendar x:Name="Calendar" >
        </ListView.Header>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout"
             Grid.Row="1">
        <Button></Button>
        <Button></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Check if it meet your requirement.

Comment: It Worked but Iam getting an error System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: You should check the itemSource of listView.